# How to get integer value from array:php

Tags: php, arrays

When I do a print_r on my $_POST, I have an array that may look like this:

```
Array
 (
    [action] => remove
    [data] => Array
    (
        [row_1] => Array
            (
                [DT_RowId] => row_1
                [name] => Unit 1
                [item_price] => 150.00
                [active] => Y
                [taxable] => Y
                [company_id] => 1
            )

    )

 )
```

The row_1 value can be anything formatted like row_?

I want that number as a string, whatever the number is. That key and the DT_RowID value will always be the same if that helps.

Right now I am doing this, but it seems like a bad way of doing it:

```
 //the POST is a multidimensinal array... the key inside the 'data' array has the id in it, like this: row_2.  I'm getting the key value here and then removing the letters to get only the id nummber. 
foreach ($_POST['data'] AS $key => $value) {
        $id_from_row_value = $key;
    }
//get only number from key = still returning an array    
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $id_from_row_value, $just_id);
//found I had to use [0][0] since it's still a multidimensional array to get the id value
$id = $just_id[0][0];
```

It works, but I'm guessing there's a faster way of getting that number from the $_POST array.

Comment: You could use `array_keys()` instead of your foreach loop to get the key if you want. Then you can just use `preg_match()` instead of `preg_match_all()` to get just the number.

Comment: one problem with the bottom code is that if you have multiple rows in `$_POST['data']` you will only ever get the last key since each iteration of the loop`$id_from_row_value` is being reassigned the value of that key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$array = [
    'data' => [
        'row_1' => [],
        'row_2' => [],
    ]
];

$nums = [];
foreach ($array['data'] as $key => $val) {
    $nums[] = preg_replace('@[^\d]@', '', $key);
}

var_export($nums);
```

Outputs:

```
array (
  0 => '1',
  1 => '2',
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remember that regular expressions, used in `preg_match` are not the fastest solution. What I would do is split the string by `_` and take the second part. Like that:

```
$rowId = explode("_", "row_2")[1];
```

And put that into your loop to process all elements.

Comment: Thank you all for the support.